# I want to use ruby1.9.3 in my Mac, but it still using ruby1.8.7 after I installed the ruby1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

As you know, Ruby is pre-installed in Mac and it's version is 1.8.7

```
[zhuhuihuihui@akematoMac-mini ~] $ ruby --version 
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

For some reasons, i need to use Ruby-1.9.3 instead.

Basically, i followed these steps:

```
brew update
brew install rbenv
brew install ruby-build
rbenv install 1.9.3-p0
rbenv rehash
```

Everything works fine, but i still getting the same version(1.8.7) after i installed the 1.9.3
I can use ruby-1.9.3 only if i typed the full path, like this:

```
[zhuhuihuihui@akematoMac-mini ~] $ ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

But my system is still using Ruby-1.8.7.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x): *Afterwards you'll still need to add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to your profile as stated in the caveats. You'll only ever have to do this once.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried installing rbenv with brew, but have you done this part?

From: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

> Afterwards you'll still need to add eval "$(rbenv init -)" to your profile as stated in the caveats. You'll only ever have to do this once.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe has to do with your `$PATH`. Have you edited your `.bash_profile` to prepend the rbenv's path?

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Basically, I recommend you to make sure you've done steps 2-6 from the instructions: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after i typed

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

in my terminal, It works.